# correct SAML TLSProtocolSocketFactory configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml

I use [Spring SAML](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) to authenicate users.
Per default the SAML implementation refreshes its metadata every hour.
The initial run through `org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh()` works, but all later calls (called by a timer) fail:

```
INFO: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector - Retrying request
ERROR: org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver - PKIX path construction failed for untrusted credential: [subjectName='CONTENT_REMOVED_FOR_STACKOVERFLOW']: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
ERROR: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider - Error retrieving metadata from https://HOSTNAME/PATH?cmd=metadata
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostname(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:233)
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:250)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:260)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider$RefreshMetadataTask.run(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:521)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
DEBUG: org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider - Error occurred while attempting to refresh metadata from 'https://HOSTNAME/PATH?cmd=metadata'
org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.MetadataProviderException: Error retrieving metadata from https://HOSTNAME/PATH?cmd=metadata
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:274)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.refresh(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:260)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider$RefreshMetadataTask.run(AbstractReloadingMetadataProvider.java:521)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: SSL peer failed hostname validation for name: null
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostname(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:233)
    at org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(TLSProtocolSocketFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider.fetchMetadata(HTTPMetadataProvider.java:250)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

I traced it down to the `org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer` bean.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer">
    <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/>
    <property name="keyManager" ref="keyManager"/>
</bean>
```

In `afterPropertiesSet()` this bean overrides the previous registed (`org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory`) https protocol (`org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol`)
with `org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory`.

So the first call uses `org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory` which works, all timer calls use `org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory` which fail.

If I remove the `TLSProtocolConfigurer` from my spring configuration, all works fine. The question is, can I do that without breaking anything?
Is it a bug which I should report?

Answer (score 0):

The exception says, that it cannot verify the host name that is defined in the certificate. Hence, your Timer is executed on a host whoes name does not match the one in the certificate. So this is not a bug.

Comment: Ok, but why does `org.opensaml.ws.soap.client.http.TLSProtocolSocketFactory` not throw an exception? With it the whole `refresh()` works, with `org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolSocketFactory` it fails.

Comment: Is your "first call" and the calls from the scheduler coming from the same host(-name)? If so, then it seems that the Spring TLSProtocolSocketFactory has hostname-verification enabled by default, while the OpenSAML TLSProtocolSocketFactory has not. There should be a property or similar to set this....

Comment: Yes first and scheduler calls come from the same host. In OpenSAML TLSProtocolSocketFactory the `hostnameVerifier` is set to `XMLTOOLING_STRICT`. In the method `verifyHostname()` the host is validated without exception.

Comment: This sounds strange. What hostname is defined in your certificate and what is the source hostname of your calls, i.e. are these two identical?

Comment: For security reason I prefere not to post the hostname, I'm not sure if there is a hostname declared in the certificate. But I don't think that even matters, since in case of the exception `String hostname = sslSession.getPeerHost();` the `hostname` is `null`. This is not `null` in the first call.

Comment: I also noticed, searching the internet for `org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer`, that all spring configurations that I found disabled this bean, so maybe there is something wrong with it.

Comment: The hostname in the certificate and the hostname of the calling host have to be identical, in order for the host name verification to succeed..

Comment: Since the first call verifies the host correctly, I think they are the same.

Comment: Do you really need MetaData refreshment at all or do you only use it as it's the default?